# Ethernet driver DPC reinit messages from Yosemite kernel

Tags: macos, wifi, airport

I have one Mac (10.10.1 BuildVersion 14B25) that is experiencing periods of sluggish wireless networking.

I am seeing system.log messages around these times of the following sort:

> Jan 16 08:02:50 mac kernel[0]: ARPT: 139243.965792: wl0: 802.11 driver DPC, reinit reason[5], count[13]
>
> Jan 16 08:22:08 mac kernel[0]: ARPT: 140402.354334: wl0: 802.11 driver reinitializing, total count of reinit's[196], @'wlc_dpc':466

The count[xx] are clearly counting up each time the message is logged but the rest of the meaning escapes me. I'm not seeing anything odd or different on other Mac that are close by and Wireless Diagnostics shows nothing amiss.

Are these Airport driver DPC reinit reasons (5 in this case) documented anywhere so I can know what I might need to address or change on that Mac?

Comment: It could be simply crowded channel.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It's not. That machine and 4 others are all on 5GHZ with nothing near the channel in use. SNR is excellent, data rates between 200 and 480, quality 28 to 36. This Mac backed up 300 GB of data wirelessly the other day and other than the driver restarts is a solid workhorse.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, does that user uses boot-camp-Windows? Did you check the DPC Latency?

Comment: Is this a reading material you are looking for? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1876027?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thanks for the googles. No bootcamp, no windows. Just an OS X 10.10.1 system kernel message. It might be correlated with network file sharing mount to a 10.10 server that I'm hoping to get updates to 10.10.1 next week. None of the discussions on apple seem really relevant. Most are just laundry lists of KB articles and people with more severe WiFi issues like not being able to join a network. This mac joins fine and is fast other than when these are logged. It's not dropping the network, just I was hoping for more detail on the messages.